# Trigger change in PickList4.js from Salesforce

Tags: visualforce, javascript, picklist, dependent-picklist

How can I trigger a picklist change event inside salesforce:

We have the following code :

```
        <apex:outputPanel id="dynamicRerender">
            <apex:repeat value="{!strings}" var="eachAPI">
                <div class="dynamicClass hidden">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Case[eachAPI]}" id="sfField"/>
                </div>
            </apex:repeat>
        </apex:outputPanel>
```

and then `onComplete` of the action function we are suppose to default the values of some of the picklist. But when we try to default the value, the dependent picklist does not show up.

```
 $(".IdOfTheFieldControlllingField).val('New');
```

I think because the controlling picklist is not able to trigger the change event. Is this manually possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out its a normal change event to be triggered :

```
 $(".IdOfTheFieldControlllingField).trigger( "change" );
```